# Neural network .csv file header is not being read

Tags: pandas, csv, pytorch, neural-network

I have a neural network and it is taking training data from a .csv file, but the column name is not being found.The error says this:"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\zyman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3653, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'close'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:"

This is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_path, sequence_length):
        data = pd.read_csv(data_path, delimiter='\t')
        normalized_data = (data.iloc[:, :-1] - data.iloc[:, :-1].mean()) / data.iloc[:, :-1].std()

        self.inputs = []
        self.targets = []
        for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length - 1):
            self.inputs.append(normalized_data.iloc[i:i+sequence_length].values)
            close_price = data.iloc[i+sequence_length]['close']
            open_price = data.iloc[i+sequence_length]['open']
            if close_price > open_price:
                self.targets.append(1)  # Green candle
            else:
                self.targets.append(0)  # Red candle

        self.inputs = np.array(self.inputs)
        self.targets = np.array(self.targets)


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return torch.tensor(self.inputs[index], dtype=torch.float32), torch.tensor(self.targets[index], dtype=torch.long)



def train(model, dataset, num_generations, num_networks, num_clones, batch_size, num_epochs):
    for generation in range(num_generations):
        print(f"Generation: {generation + 1}")
        print("Training...")

        top_performers = []

        for network_index in range(num_networks):
            print(f"Network: {network_index + 1}")
            model_clone = Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
            model_clone.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())

            dataset_size = len(dataset)
            train_size = int(0.8 * dataset_size)
            train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [train_size, dataset_size - train_size])

            train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
            val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

            criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
            optimizer = optim.Adam(model_clone.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

            best_val_accuracy = 0.0

            for epoch in range(num_epochs):
                model_clone.train()
                for batch_inputs, batch_targets in train_loader:
                    optimizer.zero_grad()
                    outputs = model_clone(batch_inputs)
                    loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), batch_targets)
                    loss.backward()
                    optimizer.step()

                model_clone.eval()
                correct_predictions = 0
                total_predictions = 0

                with torch.no_grad():
                    for val_inputs, val_targets in val_loader:
                        val_outputs = model_clone(val_inputs)
                        val_predictions = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(val_outputs)).squeeze()
                        correct_predictions += (val_predictions == val_targets).sum().item()
                        total_predictions += len(val_targets)

                val_accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions

                if val_accuracy > best_val_accuracy:
                    best_val_accuracy = val_accuracy
                    model.load_state_dict(model_clone.state_dict())

            top_performers.append(model_clone)

        print("Evaluation...")
        correct_predictions = 0
        total_predictions = 0

        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, targets in dataset:
                outputs = model(inputs.unsqueeze(0))
                predictions = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(outputs)).squeeze()
                correct_predictions += (predictions == targets).sum().item()
                total_predictions += len(targets)

        accuracy = correct_predictions / total_predictions
        print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

        if generation < num_generations - 1:
            top_performers = sorted(top_performers, key=lambda m: -best_val_accuracy)[:num_clones]
            model_clones = [Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size) for _ in range(num_networks)]

            for i, performer in enumerate(top_performers):
                for j in range(num_clones):
                    model_clones[i * num_clones + j].load_state_dict(performer.state_dict())

            model = nn.Sequential(*model_clones)

        print("=" * 50)


input_size = 5
hidden_size = 64
output_size = 1
learning_rate = 0.001
batch_size = 32
num_epochs = 10
sequence_length = 10
num_generations = 100
num_networks = 100
num_clones = 10

model = Net(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
dataset = CustomDataset('C:\\Users\\zyman\\PycharmProjects\\Pulling-Data\\NeuralNetworkTrainingData.csv', sequence_length)

train(model, dataset, num_generations, num_networks, num_clones, batch_size, num_epochs)
```

This is the start of the .csv file(it is 5000 rows long)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBRsJ.png)

I don't know what to try I was googling for the past 2 hours please help

Answer (score 0):

`data = pd.read_csv(data_path, delimiter='\t')`

You are using `tab` as delimiter. Is your data `tab` separated or `comma` separated?

If it's `tab` separated, try printing data after reading it.

Comment: My data is tab seperated. It is a pandas dataframe converted with the function .to_csv to a .csv file. How can I print the data after reading it? If i try print(dataset) it just does not print it.

Comment: You can try it in jupyter notebook or in command line. Can you upload csv file or small fraction of it with question?

Comment: There is a small screenshot containing the .csv file, I cannot print it, becouse the error pops up first and stopss the rest of the code from running.

Comment: I saw the screenshot, but I want to see actual csv file. If you give data, then I can try to debug it.